# Pourquoi le subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer pourquoi on emploie le subjonctif dans cette phrase :

> Si j'avais eu son adresse, je l'**eusse mise.**

Il n'y a pas d'expression de sentiment ici, ni de locutions qui exigent le subjonctif, donc pourquoi l'employer ?

Comment: C'est une erreur, il faut utiliser le conditionnel. D'où vient cette phrase ?

Comment: @Toto Je ne sais pas d'où exactement, mon prof nous a donné des phrases sans contexte... Je sais seulement que cette phrase est par Christiane Rochefort.

Answer (score 3):

*Je **l'eusse** mise* n'est pas ici un subjonctif mais un *[**conditionnel passé deuxième forme**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/conditionnel_pass%C3%A9_deuxi%C3%A8me_forme)*, temps qui n'est plus enseigné en français moderne parce qu'inutilisé et confondu à l'écrit avec le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif.

Le sens est donc bien, sans omettre la fin de la phrase de Christiane Rochefort :

> Si j'avais eu son adresse, je **l'aurais** mise à la torture.

Références:

[BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.php?id=24141) *Conditionnel passé et plus-que-parfait du subjonctif*
    [Grevisse](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/grammaire/le-conditionnel-passe-deuxieme-forme-un-temps-perdu) *Le conditionnel passé deuxième forme : un temps perdu ?*

Answer (score 1):

On devrait utiliser le conditionnel dans la langue courante ;

- Si j'avais eu son adresse, je l'aurais mise.

On trouve des explications à partir de la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4141) mais elles ne correspondent pas exactement au présent contexte. Il semble que l'on ait un cas hybride, peut être le résultat d'une incertitude sur l'usage. La différence est que les deux verbes sont au subjonctif.

Answer (score 0):

Correctment! Passé conditionnel

condition impossible (irréel; toujours contraire aux faits)
Si + Imparfait, Présent conditionnel (présent + futur)
Si + Plus-que-parfait, Passé conditionnel (passé)

Comment: C'est probablement exact, mais la réponse telle qu'elle est écrite est incompréhensible. *Je l'eusse mise* n'est pas ici un subjonctif mais un conditionnel passé deuxième forme, qui a disparu en français moderne.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, tout à fait c'est un conditionnel passé 2e forme, je pense que ça vaudrait le coup que la réponse soit écrite de façon plus claire car on ne peut pas dire que la question ait pour l'instant reçu de réponse plus exacte...

Comment: @jlliagre quoi que quoi que.... https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouvelle_grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise/UWVcAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22+Si+j%E2%80%99avais+eu+son+adresse,+je+l%E2%80%99eusse+mise+%C3%A0+la+torture%22&dq=%22+Si+j%E2%80%99avais+eu+son+adresse,+je+l%E2%80%99eusse+mise+%C3%A0+la+torture%22&printsec=frontcover. Ça demande réflexion, non ?  C'est vrai que les deux formes étant semblables... plouf !